# Logging data and how to do multiple responses and work with variables in python

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

Here is what I am trying to accomplish: I want the code to ask for the first name and last name and write it to a text file. If one exists already I just want the information appended to the document otherwise I want it to create one and add the information. This executes just fine. I am however having trouble with ending the function. I want it to ask if I would like to enter another name after each time while accepting many forms of the answer 'yes'. I initialized the variable before the while loop and have tried many different ways to accomplish this but cannot get it to work correctly. Any suggestions? I will attach the code below.

```
import os
stillWorking = 'Yes'
while (stillWorking == 'Yes', 'yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y'): 
    if os.path.exists('.\WhoWasHere.txt'):
        firstName = raw_input('Please enter your first name: ')
        lastName = raw_input('Please enter your last name: ')
        whoWasHere = open('.\WhoWasHere.txt', 'a')
        whoWasHere.write(firstName + '\t')
        whoWasHere.write(lastName + '\t\n')
        whoWasHere.close()
        stillWorking = raw_input('Do you wish to enter another name?')
    else:
        firstName = raw_input('Please enter your first name: ')
        lastName = raw_input('Please enter your last name: ')   
        whoWasHere = open('.\WhoWasHere.txt', 'w')
        whoWasHere.write(firstName + '\t')
        whoWasHere.write(lastName + '\t\n')
        whoWasHere.close()
        stillWorking = raw_input('Do you wish to enter another name?')
print('Your name has been written to the log.')
exit = raw_input('You may now press any key to exit')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) operator in your `while` loop condition. Example -

```
while stillWorking in ('Yes', 'yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y'):
```

When you do - `(stillWorking == 'Yes', 'yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y')` , it returns a tuple , which is not empty , and hence it never exits the loop (Non-empty tuples/lists are true in Boolean context) . To show that -

```
>>> stillWorking = 'Yes'
>>> stillWorking == 'Yes', 'yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y'
(True, 'yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y')
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just teaching myself how to program so I am still have trouble with some of the beginning concepts as you can see. This made perfect sense though! Thanks for the thorough explanation!